# factorial algorithm in pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial

I've been given the following algorithm, that takes a positive integer *K* and returns a value:

```
X = 1
Y = 1
while X ≠ K do
    X = X + 1
    Y = Y * x
return Y
```

I'm supposed to figure out what it returns.

As it happens, I know the answer — it returns the factorial of *K* — but I don't understand why.

How do you go about figuring out what this pseudocode does?

Comment: Do you understand all the notations used? For example, do you know what `X = X + 1` means?

Comment: Start by making a table of the values of X and Y for each round of the while loop asuming _e.g._ K = 5.

Comment: @ruakh yes that bit i understand, i guess the main bit i dont understand @ Terje D. is the k bit and how it works, thanks again

Comment: The code in the loop is repeated as long as X is not equal to K. For each round X is increased by one (and eventually becoming equal to K), and Y is multiplied by the new value of X.

Comment: The algorithm is wrong. Consider K=0, yet fac 0 = 1 per defintion.

Comment: @Ingo The code is only claimed to work for "a positive integer K". It is not so much wrong as unnecessarily limited.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan but factorial is defined on natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now let's assume that K is 5. Therefore the factorial of 5 is 120.
Then as you enter the loop X value is 2 and y gets the value 2.(1*2)
Then the value of X is 3 after getting into loop, which then makes the value of Y 6 because (3*2).
Then the value of X is 4 after getting into loop, which then makes the value of Y 24 because (4*6).
Then the value of X is 5 after getting into loop, which then makes the value of Y 120. 
Then since X==Y the while loop exits and Y value which is the factorial is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = 1 <- this is counter which you gonna multiply in every step
Y = 1 <- this is to store the cumulative product after each step
while X ≠ K do <- until you reach K
    X = X + 1 <- increase X
    Y = Y * X <- multiply with increased X
return Y <- return the product
```

So in the loop the cumulative product goes like this `1 -> 1*2 - > 2*3 -> 6*4 -> ... -> 1*2*..*(K-1)*K` which is `K!`

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code can be simply rewritten as (in C/C++/Java),

```
for(X=1;X<=K;X++){
    Y=Y*X;
}
```

Now it describes it self :-)